# Shell script to kill a process

Tags: macos, shell

I need to implement a shell script that kills a process. The problem is that I need to do a conditional to be able to see if the process is running or not.

This is my code, but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -x  "MY_PROCCESS_NAME"]; then
    killall MY_PROCCESS_NAME
else
    echo "Doesn't exist"
fi
```

This is the error:

```
line 3: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you need a space before `]` (but it still won't solve your problem since `-x` won't tell you if a process is running or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to check if a process is running on mac os x you can use:

```
pid=$(ps -fe | grep 'process name' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

if you want to reduce the number of shell scripts you can enclose one of the characters of the name of the process in square brackets:

```
pid=$(ps -fe | grep '[p]rocess name' | awk '{print $2}')
```

combined in your test this would look like:

```
pid=$(ps -fe | grep '[p]rocess name' | awk '{print $2}')
if [[ -n $pid ]]; then
    kill $pid
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

it's a little more complicated than you would need to do under linux as you generally have the 'pgrep' command, which is the rough equivalent of the 'ps -fe | grep ... | grep -v grep'

Comment: If you're going to use `awk` anyway, skip the grep -- `awk '/[p]rocess_name/{print $1}'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. When I run your code, I am always obtaining the "Does not exist" message, even if the process is running.

Comment: Sounds like the pattern match is not finding your process. Make sure that "ps -fe | grep '[p]rocess name'" gives you a line matching the process, so for example if you were looking for WindowServer then the line would read "ps -fe | grep '[W]indowServer'"

Comment: I had an issue with the script, now is fine, but when I run the script, it kills all my machine :S, I only see the desktop image, the other programs and process disapear.

Comment: It's the usual problem of making sure that you only match your process, and not anything else - e.g. If your program is called 'inder' then the Greg of the process will also pick up on 'Finder', which would kill your desktop!

Comment: I changed the first line for this an it worked!pid=$(ps -ef | awk '/[p]rocess name/{print $2}')

Comment: This doesn't work - the first column running ps -fe is the UID, not the PID (the second column). You should end the command with `awk '{print $2}'` - note the 2

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it would work in OSX, it works in ubuntu.

but as a one liner:

`ps aux | awk '$11~/vim/ {PID = $2} END {if (PID) print "kill -9 "PID; else print "echo no process"}' | bash`

what it does is it finds a process, in this case, vim and returns the `kill -9 pid` if no string is found it returns `echo no process` it then pipes the output to bash.